# I had done <something> while doing <something>?

Tags: participles

Would it be grammatically wrong if I said

> I had taken demanding classes while actively **participating** in school activities?

or should I say

> I had taken demanding classes while actively **participated** in school activities?

Comment: You need the continuous participle *(**participating**)* in a ***while*** clause, since "while" introduces a "continuous" activity.

Comment: A simple rule:  *I am ____ing* means "I am doing the action."  *I am ____ed* means "Somebody else was doing this to me."  In this case, you were the one taking the classes, so you're *participating*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first sentence

> I had taken demanding classes **while** actively **participating** in school activities.

is correct (note it is not a question), you need to use *"-ing"* with *while*.

> while *dining*
>   while *running*
>   while *asking* a question on ELL

Your second sentence could be reformulated as

> I had taken demanding classes **and** actively participated in school activities.
>   I **took** demanding classes **and** actively participated in school activities.